# Acumatiac Data Access Class Generator not listing table names

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to start the T100 courses for Acumatica and the instructions mention to setup a development environment and then start working on some examples. The first example has you create a graph for the Country table using the PXGraph template, build the RB project so you can use the created graph in the site project, create a ListView page pointing to the graph you just created, and then use the Data Access Class Generator to create the Country class for you in the DAC folder.

Which would be great, however when I click on 'Generate Class' for the data source it brings up the DAC Generator window . . . with no tables listed. So I'm supposed to select Country but nothing is there to select. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, so if anyone has any thoughts on how this list is populated that would be great. Thanks.

[Data Access Class Generator with no tables image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuDaH.png)

Answer (score 1):

On the same place where you are trying to click Generate Class, you have to right click the page and click Refresh.
There is no shortcut, too.
I spent 2 hours ambling around after overlooking that step during tutorial.

Comment: I have seen that in the documentation and it does not help. Also, the documentation you refer to is in reference to updating the PrimaryView property, not generate a class. Regardless, this does not help me.

I am able to update the Type Name property of the data source to point to the class created in the RB project, so the RB project is definitely rebuilt and being referenced correctly in the website. Not sure what is preventing the tables from being listed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was wrong, but I closed my solution and re-opened and the next time I tried the tables were listed. Magic.

Comment: Restarting is a long-winded way of refreshing your DAC list, see my answer for how to do it much faster.